# C++ Can't use vector and string literal in cout

Tags: c++, cout

I'm a student who just learned to use C++ for a few weeks. I write C++ code on Code:: Block and I am trying to run this code to learn about vector:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> intVector;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        intVector.push_back(i+1);
    }
    cout << "Numbers in vector: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < intVector.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << intVector[i] + " ";
    }
}
```

But the output is really weird:

```
Numbers in vector: vector::_M_emplace_back_auxector::_M_emplace_back_auxctor::_M_emplace_back_auxtor::_M_emplace_back_auxor::_M_emplace_back_auxr::_M_emplace_back_aux::_M_emplace_back_aux:_M_emplace_back_aux_M_emplace_back_aux
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.047 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? Do I use vector in the wrong way?

Comment: there is a other problem,your main method should return the integer (same as `return 0;`).

Comment: @MortezaJalambadani `main` returns `0` automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the `cout` line like this:

```
 cout << intVector[i] << " ";
```

What you're trying to do is *add* an `int&` and a *string literal* -- in some compilers it will emit a warning indicating for you that you're not getting what you intended for.

For example with *Clang*:

> warning: adding '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits>::value_type' (aka 'int') to a string does not append to the string [-Wstring-plus-int]
>
> ```
>     cout << intVector[i] + " ";
>
>             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
> ```

Comment: Thank you =)) it works. I just change from C# so I'm still not familiar with C++. Thank you again

Comment: The answer fixes OP's problem (changing the code to what they intended to do) but the argumentation is wrong. OP did not have a compilation error either (since that is valid code)